# Combining two if conditions into one

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

The below works

```
{{- if hasKey (index $envAll.Values.policy) "type" }} 
{{- if has "two-wheeler" (index $envAll.Values.policy "type") }}
<code goes here>
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

while the below fails with "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

```
{{- if and (hasKey (index $envAll.Values.policy) "type") (has "two-wheeler" (index $envAll.Values.policy "type")) }}
<code goes here>
{{- end}}
```

There is no list by name "type" declared under $envAll.Values.policy.

In Go, if the right operand is evaluated conditionally, why does the last condition gets evaluated in the second code snippet? How do I solve it?

**Edit** (since it marked as duplicate):
Unfortunately, I cannot use embedded {{ if }} like it is mentioned in the other post.

I simplified my problem above. I actually have to achieve this...

```
{{if or (and (condition A) (condition B)) (condition C)) }}
    <code goes here>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: The `and` function in Go templates is not short-circuit evaluated (unlike the `&&` operator in Go), all its arguments are evaluated always. So using 2 `{{if}}` is the right way to go here.

Comment: @icza, thank you. I edited my question. Could you remove the duplicate mark if you're convinced with my edit?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the logic is something else: both `or` and `and` in templates evaluate all arguments, so the answer is still the same.

Comment: I'm looking for solution for my problem. The other answer does not solve my problem. As long as it is marked as duplicate, it won't get attention from others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** The following answer predates Go 1.18 where the argument evaluation for `and` and `or` template function changed to stop early if the results is know. The answer is only valid for prior Go versions.

---

You get an error when using the `and` function because the `and` function in Go templates is not short-circuit evaluated (unlike the `&&` operator in Go), all its arguments are evaluated always. Read more about it here: [Golang template and testing for Valid fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165642/golang-template-and-testing-for-valid-fields/51167460#51167460)

So you have to use embedded `{{if}}` actions so the 2nd argument is only evaluated if the first is also true.

You edited the question and stated that your actual problem is this:

```
{{if or (and (condition A) (condition B)) (condition C)) }}
    <code goes here>
{{ end }}
```

This is how you can do it in templates only:

```
{{ $result := false }}
{{ if (conddition A )}}
    {{ if (condition B) }}
        {{ $result = true }}
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ if or $result (condition C) }}
    <code goes here>
{{ end }}
```

Another option is to pass the result of that logic to the template as a parameter.

If you can't or don't know the result before calling the template, yet another option is to register a custom function, and call this custom function from the template, and you can do short-circuit evaluation in Go code. For an example, see [How to calculate something in html/template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814840/how-to-calculate-something-in-html-template/52815110#52815110).

Comment: For reference, just add $ to variable result: $result. Otherwise, it fails with "function "result" not defined"

Comment: @Hem Yes, you're right. I didn't try the example, just wrote it from memory. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that this behavior has changed in Go 1.18, and the `and`/`or` template functions are now short-circuit https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#minor_library_changes (yes, it's described as a "minor library change")

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the Helm [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) function to avoid the second conditional.

It looks like your code is trying to test if `.Values.policy.type.two-wheeler` is present, with the caveat that the `type` layer may not exist at all.  If there's no `type`, then `.Values.policy.type` evaluates to `nil`, and you can't do additional lookups in it.

The workaround, then, is to use `default` to substitute an empty dictionary for `nil`.  Since it's then a dictionary you can do lookups in it, and since the default is empty testing for any specific thing will fail.

```yaml
{{- $type := $envAll.Values.policy.type | default dict }}
{{- if has "two-wheeler" $type }}
<code goes here>
{{- end }}
```

You can put this into a one-liner if you want

```yaml
{{- if has "two-wheeler" ($envAll.Values.policy.type | default dict) }}...{{ end }}
```

If you're actually going to use the value and not just test for its presence, another useful trick here can be to use the standard template `with` block instead of `if`.  If `with`'s conditional is "true" then it evaluates the block with `.` set to its value, and otherwise it skips the block (or runs an `else` block).  In particular here, if a map value isn't present, then its lookup returns `nil`, which is "false" for conditional purposes (though note other things like 0 and empty string are "false" as well).

```yaml
{{- $type := $envAll.Values.policy.type | default dict }}
{{- with $type.two-wheeler }}
{{-/* this references .Values.policy.type.two-wheeler.frontWheel */}}
frontWheel: {{ .frontWheel }}
backWheel: {{ .backWheel }}
{{- end }}
```